# Date Insertion (To_date)

Tags: php

can I insert a value (type DATE) in a table like this?

```
foreach ($hbegin as &$value) 
    foreach ($hend as &$value2) 
       $hourBegin = $_POST['hbegin'];   
       $hourEnd = $_POST['hend'];  
       $formatHour = $value.'-'.$value2; 

INSERT INTO table VALUES($formatHour);
```

Note:
`hbegin` is an array with a beginning hours
`hbend` is an array with an ending hours

Example:

```
hbegin[10,20,21]
hend[05,30,35]
```

formatHour

```
10-05
20-30
21-35
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this..

```
$newarr=array_combine($_POST['hbegin'],$_POST['hend']);
foreach($newarr as $k=>$v)
{
echo "$k-$v\n";// "prints" 10-05 followed by 20-30 and 21-35
}
```

Comment: To insert a value with type DATE in a table I just must have a String in this format '10-25' or I have to use To_Date()?